# What energy type does poison use and does it stack?

Tags: pokemon

I am new to Pokemon but not TCGs in general.

1. I have a Skrelp (Psychic Type) which has a Spit Poison ability (also Psychic Energy) that it used on Honedge which has a resistance -20 to Psychic Energy. The Spit Poison ability applies one stack of poison to the target. So does poison use the caster's or the caster's ability energy type or is it energy agnostic?
2. Can poison be cast multiple times on the same target to create multiple stacks of poison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

1. Pokemon TCG is quite different than the game. There's no "poison" type like in the game. In TCG, poison is a status. So, even if the defending pokemon has psychic resistance, it doesn't cut the poison damage, even if the poison is afflicted by a psychic pokemon.*)
2. No it doesn't stack.

I suggest you to read the basic rulebook again, it's very clear on what poison do there. I learned almost everything from the rulebook. But, since I am an old pokemon player (last played 4-5 yrs ago), so I forgot what poison exactly do. But AFAIK, it damages the affected pokemon between turns.

*) This is different if Spit Poison has initial damage attached, for example, 30. So the initial damage will be 10 (30 original - 20 resistance), aside from the poison status damage.

Comment: I did read the rules again this afternoon and I saw a few times where it mentioned that poison does not stack. I still never really saw where said poison ignores resistances though. But I'll take your word for it, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Pokemon with weakness against Fire-types don't take weakness into account when taking damage from being Burned, either.

Comment: Also of note, as of Sun & Moon expansion (at least) there is Salazzle who can inflict "severe poison" (4 damage counters per turn, rather than 1) and Seviper whose "More Poison" ability increases the damage by one counter per turn. AND there is Toxapex-GX whose "Super Intense Poison" attack does 10 damage counters per turn!

Answer (score 1):

The Pokémon TCG handles several things different from the video games.  Simple answers to your questions would be quite misleading.  So first things first:

**Type:** The Pokémon TCG has fewer Types than the video games.  TCG Types often contain two or even three of the video game Types.  The TCG Psychic Type contains the video game Psychic, Ghost, and Poison Types.  Most cards also only have a single Type even if in the video games that Pokémon has two Types.

**Weakness/Resistance:** Besides the obvious like Resistance causing a flat -20 to attack damage, another major difference is that **attacks have no Type in the TCG.**  So when you go to apply Weakness and/or Resistance, you look at the Pokémon's own Type, not what Energy when to pay for the effect.

**Poison does no damage:** Poison is a what is called a "Special Condition" in the TCG, along with Burn, Confusion, Paralysis, and Sleep.  There are other effects that attacks or Abilities can inflict on a Pokémon, but those five have special rules.  Poison in the TCG places a damage counter on the Poisoned Pokémon between turns.  Though doing damage involves placing damage counters at the end, an effect that places damage counters (like Poison) skips a lot of steps, one of those being the steps where Weakness and Resistance are applied.  **So Resistance does nothing to Poison.**

**Stack or Replace:**  Some Special Conditions stack with each other, but any time you inflict a the same Special Condition on a Pokémon, like Poisoning something which has already been Poisoned, the newer of the two replaces the older.  So you cannot use Spit Poison multiple times to increase how many damage counters are placed on it from Poison between turns.  **Some Pokémon place multiple counters with Poison!** So be careful not to replace a stronger Poison with a weaker one.  If the card doesn't specify, then it just places one damage counter from Poison between turns.